# Call to a member function where() on null (View: /home/farid/blog2/resources/views/jadwalpiket/editemployeepiket.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-8, crud, edit

I got an Error message
Call to a member function where() on null (View: /home/farid/blog2/resources/views/jadwalpiket/editemployeepiket.blade.php) when I'm trying to create a checkbox for the edit form page

**my controllers**

```
public function edit(Employeejadwalpiket $Employee, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::all();
    $jadwalpiket = Jadwalpiket::all();
    $data = Employeejadwalpiket::with('employees','jadwalpiket')->find($id);

    return view('jadwalpiket.editemployeepiket', compact('Employee','employee','jadwalpiket','data'));

}
```

**my view**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Pilih Tugas :</strong>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            @foreach ($jadwalpiket as $j)
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="jadwalpiket_id[]" value="{{ $j->id }}" @if (count($Employee->jadwalpiket->where('id', $j->id)))
                                    checked
                                @endif>

                                    {{ $j->jadwal_piket }}&emsp;&emsp;
                                </label>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**my web.php**

```
Route::get('/editemployeepiket/{id}',[EmployeejadwalpiketController::class, 'edit'])->name('editemployeepiket'); 
Route::post('/upemployeepiket/{id}',[EmployeejadwalpiketController::class, 'update'])->name('upemployeepiket');
```

please help me to fix it..

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
@if (count($Employee->jadwalpiket->where('id', $j->id))) checked @endif>
```

to

```
@if ($Employee->jadwalpiket()->where('id', $j->id)->count()) checked @endif>
```

If you use you use the query builder instead of the instance, you will avoid the error.

In all cases, you should do it differently and not call everything multiple times in your controller.

Comment: i have followed your suggestion but i got message like this "BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\EmployeeJadwalpiket::jadwalpiket() (View: /home/farid/blog2/resources/views/jadwalpiket/editemployeepiket.blade.php) "

Comment: @Ridwan60 in your code you userd the relation `$data = Employeejadwalpiket::with('employees','jadwalpiket')` how can it be not defined. did you define it as a private function ?